# Dragging over the buttons to show a word in windows form C#

Tags: c#

I have a windows form that includes a text box and 3 buttons
The text property of the first button is C.
The text property of the second button is A
Text property of the third button is R.
Is there a way to show a car word in the text box by dragging the mouse over the previous buttons?
I tried to write the code in the MouseMove event & DragEnter event but I did not get anything.
I need to click on the first button "C" then keep pressing and dragging over the other buttons to create the word "CAR" in the textBox

Comment: it's helpful to show us your code that is relevant to your question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Event `MouseHover`

```
private void BtnC_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TxtCar.Text += BtnC.Text;
    }
private void BtnA_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TxtCar.Text += BtnA.Text;
    }
private void BtnR_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TxtCar.Text += BtnR.Text;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering , is there other way to create the word rather than  using mouseHover event ??,  i want to press on first button and drag to last letter which is button R